# Timeout error with Freeform

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, file-uploads

I am new to Freeform and EE; we are using Freeform 3.1.5. I have following questions.  Please advise.  Thanks!

1. Is this version of Freeform support inline error message?
2. Our inquiry form allows users to upload multiple files.  However, when users tried to upload files with large file sizes and timeout (so failed to save and submit the form), no error message is displayed and it will just redirect users to the thank you page that we specified on “return=”. Is there any way to display error message to users when timeout?

**Updates - Here is my template:**

```
{exp:freeform:form
    collection="Field Installation Report" 
    notify="OUREMAIL@XXX.COM"
    required="customer_name|install_site|install_date"
    send_user_email="yes"  
    template="field_report_template"
    user_email_template="user_field_report_template"
    file_upload="Field Service"
    allowed_file_types="jpg|pdf|zip"
    return="support/success"
} 

<fieldset>
    <legend>Field Report</legend>
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Field Report Submitted" />
    <input type="hidden" name="fir_user" id="fir_user" value="{name}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="form_entry_date" id="form_entry_date" value="{current_time format='%Y-%m-%d'}"/>    

    <p><label for="customer_name">Customer Name<span class="required">*</span>:</label>
    <input type="text"  id="customer_name" name="customer_name" /></p>

    <!-- more fields.... -->

    <fieldset class="photo">
        <legend>Photos or Documentation</legend>
        <p><input type="file" name="file1"></p>
        <p><input type="file" name="file2" ></p>
        <p><input type="file" name="file3" ></p>
        <p><input type="file" name="file4" ></p>
        <p><input type="file" name="file5" ></p>
        <p><input type="file" name="file6" ></p>
    </fieldset>

    <p><label for="email">Email Confirmation To:</label>
    <input type="email"  id="email" name="email" value="{email}" /></p>
    <p><input class="submit" value="Submit Form" type="submit"></p>
</fieldset>
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Answer (score 1):

Freeform 3.1.5 is an old version that isn't supported anymore. We strongly recommend upgrading to Freeform 4.x. See the compatibility chart to make sure your version of EE is compatible with Freeform 4.x: http://www.solspace.com/software/compatibility

The following guide is also strongly recommended after upgrading to Freeform 4.x when coming from 3.x: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/upgrade_3.x-4.x/

> ***Very Important*: Please make a reliable backup of your database and files before upgrading. It's also recommended to run the upgrade on a test/development installation before doing this on a live site**. This way, if something goes wrong, you can revert to your current status.

As for your questions:

1. No. Inline error messages are only supported in Freeform Pro 4.x
2. This is difficult to answer without seeing your template code. Also, in general uploading large files requires PHP to be setup to accept large files and not timeout before. These settings are usually found in your `php.ini` file. Upgrading Freeform is still recommended, however. File upload handling is also different in Freeform 4.x. Once upgraded, you would need to show your template code if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks for replying!  Unfortunately we are stuck at the old version of EE v2.1.3 currently due to incompatible issues (long story).  We did purchased the Freeform Pro a while back but as far as I know we didn’t use it. We will look into the possibilities of upgrading both EE and Freeform.  Meanwhile, for uploading files with Freeform 3.1.5, will it able to generate error when timeout?

Comment: I understand that we can change php.ini setting to allow larger files.  However, the problem that we have now is some oversea users have slow internet connection so it will timeout even they are trying to upload small files (like 1.5-2MB), so I would like to be able to show them the timeout error instead of redirecting them to thankyou page even upload failed.  I have added our template code in above.  Thanks!!

Comment: What would usually time out is the server/browser, not Freeform. In those cases, Freeform can't be used to display. See this thread for php.ini settings to look for (in addition to file size, there are timeout values): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578190/can-file-uploads-time-out-in-php . The only other odd behaviour is being redirected to a thank you page instead of getting a browser timeout message. Are you sure the folder permissions and uploaded file format are correct? Have you tried with a smaller version of the same file extension? (eg. bigfile.jpg (3 Mb) vs smallfile.jpg (20 kb))

Comment: Yes, I have tried uploading a smaller version of the same file extension and it works. The form and file got saved and uploaded properly and redirected me to the thank you page.  Actually I said it wrong earlier.  When a required field is not filled in, it directed me to the error message page (where template is defined on Design > Message Pages > User Messages).  But when timeout error or filesize exceed limit on upload file, it directs me to the homepage of our website with no error message displayed. I’ve checked and the site doesn’t have redirection on error to homepage though. Odd..

Comment: Have you tried increasing, to high values, the php.ini values for `max_input_time`, and `max_execution_time`?